# .sum() and .max() not included in Systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

Why does the error say sum/max "is not declared under this prefix"? I thought Systemverilog had these array reduction functions included. Do I need to add a library or something to use them?
Code below:

```
module compare_block (clk, result, data, led);

    parameter taps = 50; //number of fir filter taps
    parameter data_width = 8; //width of data input including sign bit
    parameter coeff_width = 32; //width of coefficients including sign bit
    parameter size = 4096;

    
    input clk;
    input [(data_width + coeff_width + $clog2(taps) - 1):0] result; //from filter
    input [(data_width-1):0] data; //precalculated 1 Hz sine wave
    output led;
    
    reg [(data_width + coeff_width + $clog2(taps) - 1):0] filt_sig;
    reg [(data_width-1):0] comp_sig;
    reg [(data_width-1):0] ans_sig;
    
    integer i;
    integer ii;
    integer sum_array;
    integer array_avg;

        
    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
        filt_sig [(data_width + coeff_width + $clog2(taps) - 1):0]<= result[(data_width + coeff_width + $clog2(taps) - 1):0];
        comp_sig [(data_width-1):0]<= data[(data_width-1):0];
        end
        
    always @(*)
        begin
        for (i=0; i < size; i=i+1)
            ans_sig[i] = filt_sig[i] - comp_sig[i]; 
        end
        assign sum = ans_sig.sum(); //with (int'(item)) 
        assign array_avg = sum >> 'd12; //dividing by 4096 (size) to get mean of signal deviation
        
    integer max_array = ans_sig.max();
    integer error_val = 0.5*max_array;  
    always @(*)
        begin 
        if (array_avg < error_val) begin
            led <= 'b1; 
        end else begin
            led <= 'b0;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: `sum` and `max` are methods available for unpacked arrays; but you are using them on packed arrays. I'm not sure the best solution to changing your code however as I'm not sure I fully understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array reduction methods are defined for unpacked arrays. Instead of `sum()`, you can use `$countones(ans_sig)`. I'm not sure what you are trying to compute with `max()`. Maybe you meant to declare `ans_sig` as an unpacked array.